# Prove matrix is linear independence given $M^n=0$

Tags: matrices

Denote matrix $M \in M_{n×n}$($\mathbb{R}$)  $st$ $M^n=0$ and $n \in $$\mathbb{N}$. Prove that I, M, · · · , $M^{n−1}$ are linearly independent $\iff$ $M^{n−1} \neq 0$. 
Started by assuming linear independence as $r_1×I+r_2×M...+r_{n-1}×M^{n-1}=0$ and prove the consequent. Tried a proof by contradiction: assume that $M^{n−1}$ = $0$. Then the sum would not be linearly independent. Is this on the right track? No idea where to go from here.
More help with the opposite direction also needed.

Answer (score 1):

The forward direction is quite straightforward. Let us prove the contrapositive of this statement. If $M^{n-1}$ were zero, then the nontrivial linear combination composed of only $M^{n-1}$ yields zero, so the elements cannot be independent.

For the backward direction, we will also prove the contrapositive: if $I, M, \cdots , M^{n-1}$ are dependent, then  $M^{n-1} = 0$. Suppose there is a nontrivial linear combination of these elements yielding zero, and let $M^k$ be the smallest power of $M$ that has a nonzero coefficient in this linear combination. Multiplying on both sides of the linear combination by $M^{n - k - 1}$, we obtain the equation $M^{n-1} = 0$ as desired, since by assumption all terms with lower powers of $M$ are zero and all terms with higher powers have power at least $n$ and are hence annihilated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Proving $M^{n-1} = 0 \implies$ the set $\{I,M,\dots,M^{n-1}\}$ is linearly dependent (not linearly independent) is easy: simply note that any set that includes the zero-vector (or in this case the zero matrix, since our vector space is that of the set of matrices) must be linearly dependent.

The inverse implication is trickier.  Suppose that $M^{n-1} \neq 0$, and suppose that $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{n-1}$ are such that
$$
c_0 I + c_1 M + \cdots + c_{n-2} M^{n-2} + c_{n-1} M^{n-1} = 0.
$$
We want to show that the coefficients $c_0,\dots,c_{n-1}$ must all be zero, showing that the set is linearly independent. Multiply both sides of the above equation by $M^{n-2}$ and simplify; what does this tell you about the coefficients?